# How do I execute a "fire and forget" Oracle stored procedure in ODP.Net?

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures, odp.net

I'm trying to resolve a thread blocking issue in an API that calls an Oracle DBMS's `dbms_snapshot.refresh` stored procedure. It is very long running in this case.

The existing code has what you might expect:

```
await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
```

If this were a T-SQL DBMS, the command object would have a `cmd.BeginExecuteNonQuery()` method that would fire off the stored procedure without waiting for a return value. In ODP.Net's `OracleCommand` equivalent, this method does not exist.

How can I make the same call, but without the application parking and waiting for a return value?

Note: The DB is handled by a separate department; this must be a c# solution.

Comment: This is Oracle solution - see if you can use it (talk to another department?). Write a stored procedure which will call `dbms_snapshot.refresh`. Then you'd just **schedule** (using DBMS_SCHEDULER built-in package) newly written procedure and it would do the refreshing *in the background* and you won't have to wait for anything.

Comment: Unfortunately, that isn't an option.  This is something that is a temporary measure until we complete migrating from an old application to a new one, and the DBAs won't approve temporary changes.  Thus why I said I needed a C# solution.

Comment: I see. Unfortunately, I don't speak C#. I hope someone else will be able to assist.

Comment: Open a new thread with a dedicated connection and execute it in background.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit can you provide that as an answer with example?

Comment: You can use `Task.Run()` to run your method in the background without having to manually handle threads.

Comment: Which ODP.NET version are you using? In the past, Oracle's provider faked asynchronous operations. There's no Github repo to check now but a [conference sample from 2022](https://github.com/oracle/dotnet-db-samples/tree/f5bd7cf6d7d868a049bf5339aa1bd2f9f067cc32/session-demos/2022/oracle-cloudworld) showcases async operations. Given that `async/await` were 10 years old by that point, that demo probably showed a *new* capability

Comment: It's several years ago, when I learned it in a training but I never used it in practice. But you should find many examples in the internet doing it. [Class Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task?view=net-7.0) might be a good starting point.

Comment: What's the *actual* problem with `await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();`? `await` doesn't block the application nor does it cause anything to run in the background. It awaits *without blocking* for the asynchronous operation to complete, releasing the current thread to do other work. When the async operation completes, it resumes execution in the next statement. If you use a recent ODP.NET version with *proper* async operations, `await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();` won't block anything. If the method is fake though, it will block until completion and return the result wrapped in a completed `Task`

Answer (score 0):

Compared to the "Begin..." call, you could just remove the `await`

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
```

That is the equivalent of the "Begin..." pattern call. However, neither is actually "fire & forget", because if you close the database connection and cancel the transaction, I guess the database will stop and roll back. So, you still need to "fire & wait", you are just free to do so asynchronously.